# Java "string index out of bounds"

Tags: java

The program below is supposed to find the average letter in a string. Ex: "abc" the average is "b". When I run the program I get the error message below. Thanks for your help!
PROGRAM:

```
import java.util.*;
public class AvLetter{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a phrase");
String s = scan.nextLine();
s = s.toLowerCase();
int letterCount = 0; int sum = 0; char c;

for(int pos= 0; pos< s.length(); pos++){ 
  c=s.charAt(pos);
  if  (Character.isLetter(c)) {
  sum = sum + (int)s.charAt(c);
  letterCount++;
  System.out.println((char)(sum/letterCount));
  }
}
}
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 97
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at AvLetter.main(AvLetter.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

Comment: Did you try understanding the error, and why it might appear? What did you conclude so far?

Comment: @Rebecca Just out of curiosity, are you a CS 121 student at Umass Amherst?

Comment: @rohanbk Please say you're her teacher, and she just flunked.

Comment: @bzlm I'm the course TA. Close enough.

Comment: @rohanbk Method of solving homework assignment out of range. ;)

Comment: @bzlm Out of range exception that you can catch.

Comment: @rohanbk You drive a hard bargain.

Answer (score 8):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 97 at
java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686) at AvLetter.main(AvLetter.java:14) at
...
```

The stack trace is telling you that something is going wrong on your line 14 (which is line 13 in what you posted above).  What is on line 14?  What are you expecting that method call to do and what does the documentation say it actually does?  Does your use of it on line 14 make sense compared to your use of it on line 12?

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = sum + (int)s.charAt(c);
```

you mean

```
sum = sum + (int)s.charAt(pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to get the character in your string, s, at index c, which is the ASCII value of the character at pos.

What it seems you're intending to do is add the integer value of c to the sum, if it is, you should have

```
sum += (int)c;
```

since c is already the character you want, so there's no need to re-access it.

Also, you may have intended to have the `System.out.println` outside of your for loop.

Comment: You just passed CS 121. Congratul... no, wait

Comment: @bzlm, I'm well past 100 level CS classes…

Comment: Obviously, though the 101 in sarcasm probably wouldn't harm.

Comment: Haha, tone + internet = fail, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry. It was a reference to the comments to the original question. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
sum = sum + (int)s.charAt(c);
```

is the error.  "c" is the value of your character (in your test case, it turned out to be 97) which is clearly not in the range of your String (if you were testing something like abc).

Since 97 is already the value of c you can just say

```
sum = sum + c;
```

Also note that letterCount is not very useful because it counts the length of the String, which is already obtainable by s.length().